# Elasticsearch get all parents with no children

Tags: elasticsearch

Originally I've been trying to get a list of parents and a single most recent child for each one of them. I've figured how to do that with the following query

```
{"query": 
  {"has_child": 
    {"inner_hits": 
      {"name": "latest", "size": 1, "sort":
        [{"started_at": {"order": "desc"}}]
      }, 
     "type": "child_type", 
     "query": {"match_all": {}}
    }
  }
}
```

But the problem is — the results do not include parents with no children. Adding `min_children: 0` doesn't help either. So I thought I could make a query for all parents with no children and combine those two in a single `OR` query. But I'm having trouble building such a query. Would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is your query:

```
    {
      "query":{
        "bool":{
          "should":[
            {
              "bool":{
                "must_not":[
                  {
                    "has_child":{
                      "type":"child_type",
                      "query":{
                        "match_all":{}
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "has_child":{
                "inner_hits":{
                  "name":"latest",
                  "size":1, "sort":[{"started_at": {"order": "desc"}}]
                },
                "type":"child_type",
                "query":{
                  "match_all":{}
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: May I ask a question about performance? Would it be good for this request or should I remodel my data? =)

Comment: Performance should be fine. However using nested type instead of parent-child would be a little bit faster.

Answer (score 1):

Another point: just use `must_not` for `has_child` will not only show parents without child, but all the child(s) as well, because they all don't have any child...

So another limitation should be added in the `bool` query:

```
{
  "query":{
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "has_child": {
            "type": "<child-type>",
            "query": {
              "match_all": {}
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "<the join field>": {
              "value": "<parent-type>"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```