# Return parent records even if no child records query matches

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-opensearch

(this is actually AWS OpenSearch, which I believe is a fork of Elastic Search 7.x)

So in this contrived example, I have a parent-child relationship between manufacturer and products.  I want to return "acme" information and all of the products.  Some of the products may be embargoed (not ready to be listed to the public).  For a new company, like acme, it only has new embargoed products, so when I run this query, I do not get back the company info.  I tried using `"min_children": 0,` but I still do not get back the manufacturer.

For this query, other manufacturers are returned if they have at least one product that is not embargoed, so it's something about has_child hits not returning any products.

```json
{
    "track_total_hits": true,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "has_child": {
                        "inner_hits": {
                            "name": "manf_products",
                            "size": 100
                        },
                        "min_children": 0,
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "should": [
                                    {
                                        "range": {
                                            "embargo_date": {
                                                "lt": "now/s"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "product"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "manuf": {
                                        "value": "acme"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Elasticsearch get all parents with no children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41283486/elasticsearch-get-all-parents-with-no-children)

Comment: Also, please read [this](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/32949) git hub issue where they have mentioned that when you configured `min_children` as `0` then `It currently behaves as a value of 1, that is if there is no at least 1 child matching a specified constrained, a parent document is not returned.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum value of min_children is 1. [This](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/32949) can give you more info on this.

Below query will return parents and child docs which are not embargoed. It will return parent if no child non embargoed child exists

```
{
  "track_total_hits": true,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "has_child": {
            "inner_hits": {
              "name": "manf_products",
              "size": 100
            },
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "should": [
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "embargo_date": {
                        "lt": "now/s"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            "type": "product"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [
              {
                "has_child": {
                  "inner_hits": {
                    "name": "manf_products",
                    "size": 100
                  },
                  "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "should": [
                        {
                          "range": {
                            "embargo_date": {
                              "lt": "now/s"
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  "type": "product"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "manf": {
              "value": "acme"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That is definitely NOT straight forward.  But it certainly works!  Many thanks.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Glad could be of help